# Command shell SSIS package execution under transaction isolation read uncommitted

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ssis, locking, deadlock

Would all transactions that occur in the package in the isolation if the following is executed?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "C:\Package.dtsx"'
END TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, the pacakge itself has a default transaction (click on any blank space on the package and look on the properties) and it also has its own transaction control mechanism, where a task can be "supported, required or notsupported"

See full explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):